# Resetting text width in a nested tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm nesting a tikzpicture inside a tikzpicture, and having problems with the 'text width' parameter leaking through from the outer tikzpicture to the inner. (The nesting is pretty much unavoidable -- in my actual use case the tikzpicture s are defined in different macros.)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,nopageno}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\cost}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[fill=red!85!black,shape=circle,inner sep=0.3mm,draw=black,text=white] {\raisebox{0pt}[\height][0pt]{\bf 1}};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\cost

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[text width=10mm] {\cost};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How should I modify 'cost' so that it behaves as if text width was not set?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Package `tikz` maps the value of key `text width` to the macro content of `\tikz@text@width`. The default is empty, thus you can reset the key `text width` by option setting `text width={}`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,nopageno}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\cost}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[
      text width={},
      text height={}, % dito
      fill=red!85!black,
      shape=circle,
      inner sep=0.3mm,
      draw=black,
      text=white,
    ] {\raisebox{0pt}[\height][0pt]{\bf 1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\cost

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[text width=10mm] {\cost};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]