# Reset Tikz Style

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, default

When I use the `\CircleText` macro within a `\node` in which the `text width=` is specified, the `text width=` gets applied to `\CircleText`. Is there a way to reset the style so that `\CircleText` does not inhert the `text width=` style.  The MWE below produces:

[image]

I think, if at the start of the options to `\CircleText`, I could somehow reset *all* style to their default setting, this would work fine.

### Notes:

- One solution would be to set the `text width=` to something appropriate within `\CircleText` but all that does is deffer this problem until there is some other style that I do not want to be inherited.
- Another solution would be to create boxes for each numnber and then use `\usebox` as suggested at [Proper nesting of tikzpicture environments: Reset all PGF values to their defaults](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66028/4301).
- It has been pointed out in the comments that this is a case of a nested `tikxpicture` which is not *officially* supported and could break at any time. This can easily be remedied with the solution provided at [Is there a (simple) way to find out if a command is executed in a tikzpicture environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/412460/4301).  However, this then requires the use of a `\node` within a `\node` which does not even compile.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15334/getting-numbers-to-appear-in-circles
\newcommand*{\CircledText}[2][fill=red!40]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
        \node[
            shape=circle,
            draw=black, thick, 
            fill opacity=0.3,
            text opacity=1,
            inner sep=0.8pt,
            outer sep=0pt,
            #1
        ] (char) {#2};}%
}%

\newcommand*{\DesiredText}{\CircledText{3} Some text}


\begin{document}
Outside of tikzpicture: \DesiredText

\bigskip
Inside of tikzpicture \emph{without} ``text width='' specified):

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (4,0) {\DesiredText};
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip
Inside of tikzpicture \emph{with} ``text width='' specified):

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [text width=5.0cm] at (4,0) {\DesiredText};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am wondering if [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/420548/121799) is related.

Comment: @marmot: Seems so, I have correcte the title and will have a look at that link in a little while.

Comment: Am I missing something here? Isn't this just a case of nesting `tikzpicture`s, which isn't supported and would be liable to break at any time even if it happened to work in some particular case? I assume I'm missing something, because obviously you know this as well as I do.

Comment: @cfr: Yah it is nesting tikzpictures, but I did not know that until I created this MWE. But don't know how else to define a macro to work both within and outside of `tikz`.

Comment: @PeterGrill You need to detect it. I think `tikzmark` would be useful to look at as, if I'm remembering correctly, it does something like this.

Comment: I had a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/412456/121799), I think. At least I also wanted to create a macro that works both inside and outside a tikzpicture.

Comment: @marmot Again, you need to detect the difference - either how `tikzmark` does it or in some other way. Probably all you need is to tack a toggle switch onto the start of pictures to set a conditional true or false. However, probably there is something you can test already without the need to do this.

Comment: @cfr: Even after detecting if the macro is called within a `tikzpicture` how would I define `\CircleText` without a `node`?  Is a `\node` within a `\node` ok?

Comment: @cfr But I got a [working answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/412460/121799). Is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: However, putting one node inside another is a no-no, as far as I know. At least, `tikzmark` supplies a different macro for that case, so you'd need something more analogous to `\subnode`.

Comment: @marmot No. That's using the same technique I mentioned: you're using a different macro inside and outside the picture, so there's no nesting.

Comment: The other thing you might look at is the `tikzsymbols` package. They can be used even inside nodes inside pictures because they get saved to boxes. (At least, I think that's why.)

Comment: @cfr I was referring to the above discussion between you and Peter, specifically to the statement "But don't know how else to define a macro to work both within and outside of tikz". [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/412460/121799) does precisely that.

Comment: @marmot Er ... yes. You asked if there was anything wrong with it and I said no. I didn't say you couldn't have a macro work both inside and outside: my point was that you can, if that macro calls different macros depending on whether it is inside or outside. That's exactly the approach `tikzmark` takes and the answer which you got.

Answer (score 2):

You can protect the paramater you want to preserve :

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newbox\mybox

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15334/getting-numbers-to-appear-in-circles
\newcommand*{\CircledText}[2][fill=red!40]{%
    \setbox\mybox=\hbox{#2}
    \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
        \node[
            shape=circle,
            draw=black, thick, 
            fill opacity=0.3,
            text opacity=1,
            inner sep=0.8pt,
            outer sep=0pt,
            #1,text width=\wd\mybox
        ] (char) {#2};}%
}%

\newcommand*{\DesiredText}{\CircledText{3} Some text}


\begin{document}
Outside of tikzpicture: \DesiredText

\bigskip
Inside of tikzpicture \emph{without} ``text width='' specified):

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (4,0) {\DesiredText};
\end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip
Inside of tikzpicture \emph{with} ``text width='' specified):

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [text width=5.0cm] at (4,0) {\DesiredText};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use `text width={}`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/184894/43317. But the outer node could get other options like `minimum width` or `dashed` too.

Comment: Yep that will work and is the solution I am currently using. See Note 1 in the question.